# How to create a registry resource project in Eclipse for simple String resources

Tags: wso2

Using the Wizard there are a number of templates, but they are either files or xml structures. I want to create a simple registry resource to hold the server name (not a url).

I can login to Registry management console and create a simple plain/text resource. However the wizard in Eclipse doesn't seem to expose such a simple resource type.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you can create a file in the file system with proper extension and content inside there and then use the 2nd option of creating a Registry Resource by Importing an already existing resources in file system to your Registry Resources project. Developer Studio will set the proper media type for the artifact by looking at the extension of the file you create. Thus in this case make sure you create a file with ".txt" file extension.

Thanks and Regards,

Harshana